# Google Apps Script to set the List Item's Glyph font

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

In Google Docs, I'm trying to set the font for a List Item's glyph (list number).

I tried setting attributes. Only the List Item's text font is getting changed. However, the glyph (list number) font is unchanged. Is there any way to change the glyph font?

```
function TEST()
{
  var document = DocumentApp.openById("1111111111111111DocumentID111111111111111");
  var docBody = document.getBody();
  var docBodyChildrenCount = docBody.getNumChildren();

  for (var i = 0; i < docBodyChildrenCount; i++){
    var child = docBody.getChild(i);
    var childType = child.getType();  
    if (childType == DocumentApp.ElementType.LIST_ITEM) {
      var childListItem = child.asListItem();
      var listItemStyle = {};
      listItemStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY] = DocumentApp.FontFamily.TAHOMA;
      listItemStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 14;
      var bodyChildText = childListItem.setAttributes(listItemStyle);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It really seems strange you can't do this with app scripts because you can do it manually.... I'm trying to change the colour of the bullet point in my add-on Magic Rainbow Unicorns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now, it is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

No mention of Glyph Font in the docs, only Glyph type. You can set Glyph type by using [setGlyphType(glyphType)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/list-item#setglyphtypeglyphtype) like:

```
var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();

 // Insert at list item, with the default nesting level of zero.
  body.appendListItem("Item 1");

  // Append a second list item, with a nesting level of one, indented one inch.
  // The two items will have different bullet glyphs.
  body.appendListItem("Item 2").setNestingLevel(1).setIndentStart(72)
      .setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.SQUARE_BULLET);
```

from the [Enum GlyphType](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/glyph-type) sample.

Comment: Thank you. It looks like, with the current version, there is no way to change the font of the glyph.